# Prevent vscode jest extension interpreting cypress tests as jest tests

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app, cypress

I have a create-react-app project with both jest `(in ./src/components)` and cypress `(in ./cypress)` tests. I have separate commands in my `package.json` file to run both test suites, and everything works as expected.

My problem is with the `vscode` jest extension (`orta.vscode-jest`), which interprets my `cypress` tests as jest tests and tries to run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a line to my `.vscode/settings.json` file, telling the `vscode` jest extension (`orta.vscode-jest`) to use the correct jest command

```
{
  "jest.pathToJest": "npm run test:jest --"
}
```

Where the `test:jest` command is defined in my `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts: {
    "test:jest": "CI=true react-scripts test",
  }
}
```